# Dynamic HTML containers

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I need to create dynamic html, I have an input text in which I want to put a name and when pressing enter a container is created

Title of container

```
 <span><i class="fas fa-users"></i> Grupo de usuarios 1</span>
```

Code container

```
    <div class="card-top">
  <div class="card-header">
    <span><i class="fas fa-users"></i> Grupo de usuarios 1</span>
    <div class="card-header-actions save-button">
    <a href="" class="card-header-action" target="_blank">
    <small class="text-muted" (click)='saveGroup()'><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i> GUARDAR</small>
    </a>
    </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="pacientes-box" cdkDropList #pendingList1="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="terapeutasgrupouno" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[pendingList3]" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
      <div class="grupo-terapeuta" *ngFor="let item of terapeutasgrupouno" [cdkDragData]="item" cdkDrag><i class="fas fa-user-md fa-icon"></i> {{item}}</div>
      <p class="dragdrop" *ngIf="terapeutasgrupouno == ''"><i class="fas fa-user-md fa-icon"></i> Arrastra un terapeuta</p>
    </div>

    <div class="pacientes-box" cdkDropList #pendingList="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="pacientesgrupouno" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[pendingList3]" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
      <div class="grupo-paciente" *ngFor="let item of pacientesgrupouno" [cdkDragData]="item" cdkDrag><i class="fas fa-user-injured fa-icon"></i> {{item}}</div>
       <p class="dragdrop" *ngIf="pacientesgrupouno == ''"><i class="fas fa-user-injured fa-icon"></i> Añade pacientes</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFiJW.png)

[image]
thnx!

Comment: use`input()` and pass the data

Comment: @ram12393 and with Angular?

Comment: yeah of course! you can do in angular

Comment: Than @ram12393 but can you help me a little more :S thnx

Comment: okay fine !. Tell me, what I need to help?

Comment: @ram12393 I do not understand how I should apply :'c

Comment: check this link [https://alligator.io/angular/inputs-angular/ ]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for, correct me if I'm wrong :

```
<input name="input" (keydown.enter)="create()" type="text"/>
<template #create></template>
```

I'm going to assume that your container html is its own component called `ContainerComponent`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.less']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private factory: ComponentFactoryResolver){ } // remember to import

  @ViewChild('create', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef;

  create(): void {
    const self = this;
    self.container.clear();
    self.container.createComponent(self.factory.resolveComponentFactory(ContainerComponent));
  }
}
```

So that when you type in a name and hit enter the create method is run and your container is created in replaced into the template tag. I hope this gives you an idea of one approach to what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: Hello @Ashwyb horton thanx for your reply. I have one component called gruposcomponent.ts, .html... in this file I have all html and I try...

Comment: ok man, so when you load your angular application does it work the way you expect? and if not have you been able to identify what the problem is. You can check for the problem by hitting F12 in your browser and navigating to the console tab in the popup...

Comment: weird...i'm not sure i can be of further assistance man, from looking at your code above it seems to me that it should have worked...in any case, this is not one of the more difficult tasks in angular and you could probably find tutorials on it on youtube or something.

Comment: Hello, @Ashwyn Horton very thanx for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Ashwyb horton thanx for your reply. I have one component called gruposcomponent.ts, .html... in this file I have all html and I try...

```
 import { ComponentFactoryResolver, Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild, Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
    import { copyArrayItem, CdkDragStart, CdkDragExit, CdkDragEnter, CdkDragEnd, DragDropModule, CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray, transferArrayItem, CdkDrag } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-grupos',
      templateUrl: './grupos.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./grupos.component.css']
    })
    export class GruposComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor(private factory: ComponentFactoryResolver){ 
      } 
      @ViewChild('create', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef;

      create(): void {
        const self = this;
        self.container.clear();
        self.container.createComponent(self.factory.resolveComponentFactory(GruposComponent));
      }


  ngOnInit() {
  }

  papelera = [];
    pacientesgrupouno = [];
  terapeutasgrupouno = [];
  grupo2 = [];

    terapeutas = [
    'Ana lopez',
    'Erica sanchez',
    'Marta Sanchez',
    'Mario Gonzales',
    ];

    pacientes = [
    'Emilio Escobar',
    'Daniel Bobis',
    'Gustavo Verdejo',
    'Pablo Ramos'
    ];

  droptrash(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
  if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
    console.log('dropped Event', `> dropped '${event.item.data}' into '${event.container.id}'`);
    moveItemInArray(
      event.container.data, 
      event.previousIndex, 
      event.currentIndex);
  } else {
      console.log('dropped Event', `> dropped '${event.item.data}' into '${event.container.id}'`);
      transferArrayItem(
        event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex);
    }
  }

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
  if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
    console.log('dropped Event',`> dropped '${event.item.data}' into '${event.container.id}'`);
    moveItemInArray(
        event.container.data, 
        event.previousIndex, 
        event.currentIndex);
  } else {
      console.log('dropped Event',`> dropped '${event.item.data}' into '${event.container.id}'`);
      copyArrayItem(
          event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex);
    }
  }

  saveGroup(){
    console.log(this.grupo2);   
  }
}
```

and my html is..

```
    <div class="row" id="create-groups">

  <!-- PRIMERA COLUMNA -->
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="form-group top-search">
        <div class="form-group has-add-group">
          <span class="fas fa-users form-control-group"></span>
          <input type="text" (keydown.enter)="create()" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre del nuevo grupo...">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- PRIMER BLOQUE -->
    <template #create></template>

    <div class="card-top">
      <div class="card-header">
        <span><i class="fas fa-users"></i> Grupo de usuarios 1</span>
        <div class="card-header-actions save-button">
        <a href="" class="card-header-action" target="_blank">
        <small class="text-muted" (click)='saveGroup()'><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i> GUARDAR</small>
        </a>
        </div> 
      </div>

      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="terapeutas-box" cdkDropList #pendingList1="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="terapeutasgrupouno" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[pendingList3]" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
          <div class="grupo-terapeuta" *ngFor="let item of terapeutasgrupouno" [cdkDragData]="item" cdkDrag><i class="fas fa-user-md fa-icon"></i> {{item}}</div>
          <p class="dragdrop" *ngIf="terapeutasgrupouno == ''"><i class="fas fa-user-md fa-icon"></i> Arrastra un terapeuta</p>
        </div>

        <div class="pacientes-box" cdkDropList #pendingList="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="pacientesgrupouno" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[pendingList3]" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
          <div class="grupo-paciente" *ngFor="let item of pacientesgrupouno" [cdkDragData]="item" cdkDrag><i class="fas fa-user-injured fa-icon"></i> {{item}}</div>
           <p class="dragdrop" *ngIf="pacientesgrupouno == ''"><i class="fas fa-user-injured fa-icon"></i> Añade pacientes</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- SEGUNDO BLOQUE -->
    <div class="card card-bottom">
      <div class="card-header">
        <span><i class="fas fa-users"></i> Grupo de usuarios 2</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body" cdkDropList #pendingList2="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="grupo2" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[pendingList3]" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <div class="grupo-paciente" *ngFor="let item of grupo2" [cdkDragData]="item" cdkDrag><i class="fas fa-user-injured fa-icon"></i> {{item}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- SEGUNDA COLUMNA -->
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <!-- PRIMER BLOQUE -->
    <div class="card card-bottom">
      <div class="card-header">
        <span><i class="fas fa-users"></i> Pacientes</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body" cdkDropList #pacientesList="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="pacientes" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[pendingList, pendingList2]" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group has-search">
              <span class="fa fa-search form-control-feedback"></span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar...">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="paciente" *ngFor="let item of pacientes" [cdkDragData]="item" cdkDrag><i class="fas fa-user-injured fa-icon"></i> {{item}} </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- TERCERA COLUMNA -->
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <!-- PRIMER BLOQUE -->
    <div class="card card-bottom">
      <div class="card-header">
        <span><i class="fas fa-users"></i> Terapeutas</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body" cdkDropList #terapeutasList="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="terapeutas" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[pendingList1]" (cdkDropListDropped)="droptrash($event)">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group has-search">
              <span class="fa fa-search form-control-feedback"></span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar...">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="terapeuta" *ngFor="let item of terapeutas" [cdkDragData]="item" cdkDrag><i class="fas fa-user-md fa-icon"></i> {{item}} </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- SEGUNDO BLOQUE -->
    <div class="card card-bottom card-trash">
      <div class="card-header">
        <span><i class="fas fa-trash"></i> Papelera</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-trash-body" cdkDropList #pendingList3="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="papelera" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[pendingList, pendingList2]" (cdkDropListDropped)="droptrash($event)">
        <img class="papelera" src="assets/images/trash.svg" alt="papelera">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```